# Will Delphi 6 debugging work correctly on Windows 10?

Tags: delphi, debugging, windows-10, delphi-6

I've got a legacy Delphi 6 program that's worked fine on many earlier versions of Windows but that crashes on Windows 10.  To debug the problem, I've installed Delphi 6 with updates 1 + 2 on a Windows 10 machine.  When Delphi starts, it says the Just-in-Timer debugger is set to bordbg60.exe but needs to be changed to bordbg61.exe.  If I answer "Yes", Delphi announces "Failed to set data for 'Debugger'" and hangs.  If I answer "No", Delphi proceeds and apparently works OK, including debugging features like stepping through lines of code, although I haven't yet found the cause of the Windows 10 crash.

Do I really need to change from bordbg60.exe to bordbg61.exe, and if so how can I do that since approving the change fails?

Comment: Did you run it as admin? Does it help to apply compatibility shims?

Comment: Also ensure that Delphi 6 was installed NOT in its default C:\Program Files location, but e.g. in a c:\Delphi6 folder. Vista made the C:\Program Files folder read-only.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Or install it in the program files folder and apply a permissive ACL to the bin directory.

Comment: I went through a similar scpheel with an old delphi app that stopped working on Windows 10 - it came down to a locale change that messed up everything in terms of data formatting and loading from the database. There are many factors, but do try some of the things I tried with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937771/error-loading-database-on-lyrix-exe-delphi-7-legacy-application-on-windows-10/39937772#39937772

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Just in Time debugger, then yes, it is `BORdbg61.exe` rather than `BORdbg60.exe`.

However, Just in Time debugging is not what you are doing here, so there's no need for you to do this.  What's more changing the Just in Time debugger has global consequences for your system. Unless you need to do Just in Time debugging with Delphi 6, then in my opinion you should not make the change. Decline the offer to change and check the box that stops the question being asked every time you start up.

As you have found out, there's no problem using the Delphi 6 debugger on Windows 10.

Comment: Didn't realize the JIT debugger was different than the usual debugger.